# How to combine multiple async RxJava Observables?

Tags: java, rx-java

What's the best way to subscribe to two different Observables and then block until both are complete?

```
    Observable<Integer> o1 = getSomeInts();
    Observable<Long> o2 = getSomeOtherLongs();

    o1.forEach(it -> sendSomeEvent(it)); // doesn't have to be forEach
    o2.forEach(it -> sendSomeOtherEvent(it));

    // block until o1 and o2 are complete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it:

```
Observable.merge(
        o1.doOnNext(it -> sendSomeEvent(it)).ignoreElements(),
        o2.doOnNext(it -> sendSomeOtherEvent(it)).ignoreElements())
    .count().toBlocking().single();
```

Comment: oops had used forEach instead of doOnNext, fixed